# Featured section for my apps in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

When I launch Play store application on my phone then it takes me to Google Play with different sections (Featured, Top Paid, Top Free, etc.) appearing.

My requirement is that when I go to Google Play then it should show me a section for my company apps (My featured section) in Google Play. Can I do it?

One thought is that I supply a URL to the Google Play passing on some parameters to get my featured section.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement is that when I go to Google Play then it should show me a section for my company apps (My featured section) in Google Play. Can I do it?

No. Google Play is not your app.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. When I have to directly go to an app in the Google Play then I can use a URL. Can I have a URL where it shows me a listing of apps that will depend upon the parameters passed in the URL. E.g. apps that belong to a company.

Comment: @InnovationM: "Can I have a URL where it shows me a listing of apps that will depend upon the parameters passed in the URL." -- only what Tim noted in his answer (you can bring up a list of apps for a single publisher). Moreover, this would not magically appear "when [you] go to Google Play", but only when you in your own application trigger that URL. And, this list would not be "a section for my company" alongside "Featured, Top Paid, Top Free, etc.".

Answer (score 2):

You can't manipulate what apps appear in the featured apps section (except by creating high quality apps of course)

But you can open up to a page that will list all of your applications by forming a URL like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=[YourMarketEnabledGoogleAccountName]
```

Fill in your google account name. When this url is opened on (most) devices it will prompt the user to open the link with Google Play, if they choose to do so it will show them a list of your applications.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I actually tried this today. Wanted to understand more on what all we can do using this URL and parameters we supply.

Comment: Very little, unfortunately there is no real API for accessing market material. What information is available is all located here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent The only real options are search by term, search by title, or search by developer.